# Node app fails to hit API after Deployment to Heroku. It says err::Connection Refused

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, angular7

I've deployed my Node app to heroku. It worked all good and fine but later it failed to hit any api end point. The console has an err::connection refused. 
[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO7kz.png)

I tried re-deployment but still the problem persists.

Comment: Did you do production build for deployment?

Comment: @Raahul Yes. i did ng build --prod and copied the dist folder contents to the public directory of my node api folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, it seems that you are making HTTP calls on localhost:8080, not on your Heroku instance.

Comment: yes. But that should not happen i suppose. coz i removed that from everywhere in my code before deployment.